# enable php parsing within html file for zend server

Tags: php, apache, zend-server

I recently installed the zend server in my windows based development server along with zend studio and the zend gaurd. I am new to the whole zend thing and here is the problem which has me frustrated and making me wonder if I shouldnt use zend server.
A few of my .html files has `<?php .... ?>` scripts inside them, I need to be able to parse `.html` as `.php`
It should have been simple enough adding

```
addtype application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

to the httpd.conf file and restarting apache should have done that. But when i add that line or a variation of it for php5 and so all that happens is the server starts to download files with .html files instead of loading it. I have spent hours trying to solve this and I am really frustrated. Can anyone in here who have worked with zend server earlier let me know how to do it? I just purchased an Enterprise edition and now am wondering if I just wasted my money.

Answer (score 0):

check your php module is loaded, save your .html file with .php extension. To run php code file should have proper extension.

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/mod_php5.so
```

to check available module use below command

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

or php code as

```
print_r(apache_get_modules());
```

Comment: The php module must have been loaded because it is parsing files with .php just fine. Even then to be clear how should i check if its loaded properly? Should I be doing a `echo phpinfo();`

Comment: This is what I get on running the php code `Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_get_modules()`